# how to group by date in pandas . I'm having 48 entries for a single date i.e 30 min interval

Tags: pandas, data-science, pandas-groupby

please find the input and output below. Input in the code and output in the image.
input:

```
    time    value      index_no     date    block_out   no_load
0   2018-07-16 00:30:00 1   2.0 2018-07-16      
1   2018-07-16 01:00:00 -1  3.0 2018-07-16   3.0    
2   2018-07-16 01:30:00 -1  4.0 2018-07-16   4.0    
3   2018-07-16 02:00:00 -1  5.0 2018-07-16   5.0    
4   2018-07-16 02:30:00 1   6.0 2018-07-16      
5   2018-07-16 03:00:00 1   7.0 2018-07-16      
6   2018-07-16 03:30:00 0   8.0 2018-07-16      8.0
7   2018-07-16 04:00:00 1   9.0 2018-07-16      
8   2018-07-16 04:30:00 -1  10.0    2018-07-16  10.0    
9   2018-07-16 05:00:00 2   11.0    2018-07-16      
10  2018-07-16 05:30:00 3   12.0    2018-07-16      
11  2018-07-16 06:00:00 2   13.0    2018-07-16      
12  2018-07-16 06:30:00 2   14.0    2018-07-16      
13  2018-07-16 07:00:00 -1  15.0    2018-07-16  15.0    
14  2018-07-16 07:30:00 1   16.0    2018-07-16      
15  2018-07-16 08:00:00 -1  17.0    2018-07-16  17.0    
16  2018-07-16 08:30:00 2   18.0    2018-07-16      
17  2018-07-16 09:00:00 2   19.0    2018-07-16      
18  2018-07-16 09:30:00 3   20.0    2018-07-16      
19  2018-07-16 10:00:00 -1  21.0    2018-07-16  21.0
```

[image]

Comment: A very well defined question! I totally understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you group by *column* in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generating random data
data = np.random.randint(0, 4, 15).reshape(5, 3)

# Wrapping it with pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# Group by column 'A'
groupbys = df.groupby('A')
```

In your specific problem you want to split your `'time'` column to `'date'`, `'time'` and then group by `'date'` but it probably won't get you anywhere, because you didn't define what kind of aggregation you want to do.

If you don't know how to split your "time" column you can use a map function and convert it to datetime object as so:

```
def to_datetime(str):
    return datetime.strptime('2018-07-16 00:30:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and than create a new column like so:

```
df['date'] = list(map(to_datetime, df['time']))
```